# Why is my server list being wiped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just opened Minecraft in the morning and noticed all my servers were gone.  I added some back and just decided to forget about it.  Then later in the day my server list was wiped again.  I then decided I need to figure out how to stop this.  All the rest of my worlds, resource packs and settings are the same and I haven't tampered with the Minecraft folder at all.  How can I stop the server list wipes?

Comment: I made an edit so it is more clear that it is the server list being wiped not the servers themselves, you can rollback if that was a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1):

Your Minecraft server list is the file named `servers.dat` saved in `%AppData%/.minecraft/` on Windows, `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/` on OS X, or `~/.minecraft/` on Linux. You might want to try to find out if this file gets changed when you edit your server list. If not, your Minecraft installation might be corrupted. Reinstalling could fix it.
If the file is saved and changed, things get very weird. First, now you can backup it. I would recommend reinstalling Minecraft and if that doesn't help, try contacting the Minecraft support.